# Type macros in C++

Tags: c++, macros, int, double

```
     #define int double
     #define double int


     int a = 5.5;
     double f = 5.5;

     cout << a << " " << f << endl;
```

Following code snippet actually outputs 5 5.5, meaning int actually means int, and double actually means double.

I am wondering how does that make sense? 
I could either believe both int and double meaning int, if defines are executed one after another, or two of them changing their meaning (if both of them are executed simultaneously), but I can't find proper explanation for this behaviour.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you not understand how the preprocessor works?

Comment: I do not, that is why I am kindly asking for an explanation.

Comment: I really do not see relevance between knowledge concerning data types and knowledge about non-recursive restriction in macro replacement, sorry.

Comment: FWIW, your example has undefined behaviour because it redefines a keyword and includes a standard header. That said, all compilers I know of will treat it like any other macro.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When preprocessor replaces macros, once macro replacement list is prepared it is *rescanned* for more macro replacement opportunities. However, this process does not allow recursive replacement.

In your case in

```
int a = 5.5;
```

`int` is seen as a macro name. Its replacement list is `double`. This replacement is rescanned for more macros. Macro name `double` is found and replaced with `int`. This result is rescanned again for more macros. Macro name `int` is found again, but this time it is not replaced since the "no recursion" rule prevents that. At this point the rescanning process stops. Your original `int` gets macro-replaced with `int`. So, effectively nothing is changed.

The same thing happens with `double`. In the very same fashion `double` gets ultimately replaced with `double`.

---

This is basically the same feature that allows us to define macro names that match existing function names. I.e.

```
#define fgets fgets
```

This does not result in infinitely recursive replacement when we do

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
```

The macro is replaced only once.

Comment: Also worth pointing out, the preprocessor macros are simple string substitutions.  They do not honor namespaces and may easily collide with other identifiers (such as exactly the collision in the OP's example!).